# Why do I have hot water from every faucet including the outside hose

Tags: plumbing

A customer recently purchased a house and when they turn on any faucet, they get hot water. The copper pipes are warm (hot) on both sides from the point where the supply splits off to the water heater.

Comment: Sounds like a hot water recirculation system without a return loop.  If that's the case the return is actually the cold water pipe.  The under sink valves for this are supposed to close thermally, but they don't work that well.  For confirmation post a picture of the hot water heater showing any piping or pumps close by

Comment: I think I found the problem. The plumber installed a temperature-regulating shower valve and never installed the cartridge as the master shower wasn't finished, allowing water to circulate through the valve and back through the cold water line. Thanks